# The number of local maximum and minimum values of $f(x) = x^4 - 4x^2$

Tags: calculus

If $f(x) = x^4 -4x^2 $ has 
$$a)$$ one local minimum value and two local maximum values 
$$b)$$ one local minimum value and one local maximum value
$$c)$$two local minimum values
$$d$$two local minimum values and one local maximum value
My turn :
$$f'(x) = 4x^3 -8x = 0 , x= 0 , x = \sqrt{2} , x=-\sqrt{2}$$
$$f''(x) = 12x^2 -8 $$
$$f''(0) < 0 , f''(\sqrt{2}) > 0 , f''(-\sqrt{2}) > 0$$
Then
The answer is d 
Is my answer is correct ? because there is anthor answer says that as $$f(\sqrt{2}) = f(-\sqrt{2}) $$
Then
the answer is b ?

Comment: Your last line is incorrect: $f''(-\sqrt 2)$ is not less than $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that your mistake is in evaluating the second derivative. It is

$$f''(\sqrt{2}) = f''(-\sqrt{2}) >0.$$

It is also valid that $f(\sqrt{2}) = f(-\sqrt{2})$. If "local minimum value" means the function value in the local minimum, b) is correct. If it means the number of local minima, d) is correct.

Comment: There is 3 values two of them are equal why do you combine the two equal values into one value ?@Jan

Comment: @HussienMohamed Since I am not sure what the meaning of the question is. There are people who describe with "local minimum value" the value of the function in the local minimum. Since $f$ has local minima in $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$ such that $f(\sqrt{2}) = f(-\sqrt{2})$, one $\textit{could}$ consider it as the same value. Depends on your notation.

Comment: Even it means the values of the function in the local minimum , the question asks for the number of these values which are 2 values but they are equal @Jan

Comment: The local minimum value means the function's value at the local minimum.